# Columns of markers

Tags: highcharts

I need to render following in highcharts:

[image: graph showing three column of markers]

**What's the correct chart type to use?**

Intuitively this seems like a column, but none of the examples are leading me in that direction. Instead, it seems as if I need a line chart without the lines.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a scatter series with an additional value displayed as a data label. Size of the marker is configurable with `marker.radius` option. Position of the markers can be adjust with `point.x` and `point.y` values and yAxis scale set with `yAxis.min` and `yAxis.max`

```
  plotOptions: {
series: {
  marker: {
    radius: 20,
    symbol: 'circle'
  },
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    x: 0, /* center a label inside the marker */
    y: 0,
    align: 'center',
    verticalAlign: 'middle', /* end center */
    format: '{point.z}', /* as a label value takes the additional z property defined in the data array */
    style: {
      textOutline: null,
      fontSize: '18px'
    }
  }
}
},
```

Example of a series config:

```
{
  keys: ['x', 'y', 'z'], /* x - pos on x axis, y - pos on y axis, z value displayed inside the marker
  data: [
    [1, 4, 6],
    [2, 2, 4]
  ],
  dataLabels: {
    color: /* label color */
  }
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/u19jux99/

[image: scatter column]

A similar result can be achieved with a bubble series with a constant bubble size (set by minSize = maxSize = constant). In this case labels are centered by default and they display z value.

```
  plotOptions: {
series: {
  maxSize: 35,
  minSize: 35,
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    style: {
      textOutline: null,
      fontSize: '18px'
    }
  }
}
},
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/u19jux99/1/

[image: bubble column]